# Where is the data cohort map?

Tags: collegescorecard

In replay to question "Ns for the earnings cohorts" @Brian1_at_Dept_of_Edu refers to a "data cohort map."  Where does one find this "data cohort map"?  There is no file with this name in any of the College Scorecard data downloads, nor any mention of it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

As of the September 2016 release, the updated cohort map is now available as a worksheet in the data dictionary here: https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/assets/CollegeScorecardDataDictionary-08-18-2016.xlsx

Answer (score 2):

The data cohort map is included as a tab in the Data Dictionary Excel file.

The Scorecard Data Dictionary was updated in September 2016 and the current version is available here:
https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/assets/CollegeScorecardDataDictionary.xlsx